# How to restart system-wide logging on a Linux server?

Tags: linux, logging, log-files

I am running a `Centos 7 Linux` server. I tried to install `rsyslog`. Because of a misconfiguration, we had to uninstall it. Since then, I see that all logs are truncated and no new logs are being created.

How do I resolve this?

Comment: Umm, reinstall it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe `rsyslog` is installed by default in CentOS 7/RHEL 7. If you remove it then there is no `syslog` service and therefore no new logs that utilize `syslog` will be created.